# Is it possible to rewrite the route of a static .txt file in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a Next.js application which has a robots-staging.txt file in the root of the public folder. I'm looking to add this to the rewrites function in next.config. This is what I have

```
async rewrites() {
    const rewriteList = [
      {
        source: '/robots-staging.txt',
        destination: '/robots.txt',
      },
    ];
    return rewriteList;
  },
```

My initial expectation was that when I hit `localhost:3000/robots.txt` this would serve the staging file, however it's not working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly that you want to proxy `/robots.txt` to `/robots-staging.txt`, you need to make the latter the destination and not the source.

Besides that, I've experienced the same issue, and I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature, but I found that using absolute paths/URLs works as a workaround as relative paths seem to be interpreted as pages:

```
 async rewrites() {
      {
        source: "/robots.txt",
        destination:
          process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
            ? "http://localhost:3000/robots-staging.txt"
            : "https://YOUR_URL/robots-staging.txt",
      },
    ];
  },
```